# AppendChild "Table" Object To "Div" on HTML page From External JS

Tags: javascript, external-js

I am having an js function. That function creates `Table` element and returns it. I have placed it on same page, then it's working. But I have made that function as `external js`. Then it's not working. How to append `Table` return in `Div` element on HTML Page from external js ?

**External JS:**

```js
// JavaScript Document
function createtbl() {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.border = "1";

  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
  cell.innerHTML = "Cell Value";

  var globaldiv = document.getElementById("globaldiv");
  globaldiv.innerHTML = "";
  globaldiv.appendChild(table);

}
createtbl()
```

```html
<div id="globaldiv"></div>
```

Comment: Depends on when and how you call it. Please show that part of the page. Does `globaldiv` even exist when you call the function?`

Comment: yes, it exists on the HTML Page

Comment: If this is a function in an external script, I suggest either passing the `id` to `createtbl()` or returning `table`. A function which only works on one specific html page does not need to be outsourced.

Comment: If you call `createtbl()` then your script will work if there is a div called `globaldiv`. If not it won't - I created a snippet for you

Comment: @Lain I have made this function as external because it is common to all the pages. Therefore instead of repeating on every page it's better to make it external.

Comment: @mplungjan Sir, I would need it external because all corresponding pages will access this function. It's working on single page if function placed on html page itself, but not externally.

Comment: It should work. See my answer for a version that adds the table if the div exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work on all pages containing a div called globaldiv

```js
// JavaScript Document
function createtbl() {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  table.border = "1";

  var row = table.insertRow(-1);
  var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
  cell.innerHTML = "Cell Value";

  var globaldiv = document.getElementById("globaldiv");
  if (globaldiv) {
    globaldiv.innerHTML = "";
    globaldiv.appendChild(table);
  }    

}
window.addEventListener("load",createtbl);
```

```html
<div id="globaldiv"></div>
```